# Should any action be taken on questions/answers that become outdated?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, outdated-information

E.g. in case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584850/is-it-possible-to-get-anchor-visited-state-from-javascript), neither the suggestions / code samples given in answers nor those in externally linked pages work any more.

It's outside the scope of to discuss why that is in this particular case, enough to see that similar natural expiry may occur from time to time and render questions and answers to carry invalid information.

Comment: You are touching on the reason we frown o link-only answers, insisting the post must be able to stand on its own even after removal of all links.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted (at least twice)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of these issues would be resolved with the inclusions of the OS, OS Version, language and language version in questions. As an example, I've worked with a system called ROS(Robotic Operating System) ROS Fuerte works very differently than ROS Groovy which works very differently than ROS Hydro which... and they all work differently on different OSs. Questions asked about ROS should, to continue the example, have this information but often they don't.

This isn't an edge case either - consider Python. Code discussion around python has the very obviously split of 'Python3' or 'not Python3'. I can guess based on the paths included in the code snippets or on the use of certain functions what OS, what version OS and what version of the language is being used. There are tags for python 2.7 and python3, but they're rarely used and, honestly, having all the python questions under 'python' is pretty awesome. It's all very well and good to consider that answers should focus on the most recent versions of all of these things, but in many situations that's not ideal or possible.

There are language and version agnostic questions to be sure. But for many questions knowing whether it applies, knowing what is different about my, the reader's, setup compared to the asker's or answerer's setup would be incredibly valuable.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.